# udev+udisks2: udisksctl gives 'Error looking up object for device'

Tags: debian, udev, ntfs, automounting, udisks

In Debian Wheezy I had a special rule for my ntfs usb hdd. When it is inserted it is mounted in /media under a specific sub-folder.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", SYMLINK+="mx%n"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/bin/mount <options>", OPTIONS="last_rule"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/bin/umount <options>"
```

Ufter I updated to Jessie it stopped working. I found out that after changes in udev you cannot use mount and it is recommended to use either udisks2 or some self-written systemd unit. I chose udisks2 and rewrote rule as follows

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", SYMLINK+="mx%n"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/bin/su storage_user -c '/usr/bin/udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/mx1 --filesystem-type ntfs --options locale=en_IE.UTF-8,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 --no-user-interaction'", OPTIONS="last_rule"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/usr/bin/udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/mx1 --no-user-interaction"
```

It doesn't work. In syslog I see:

```
Error looking up object for device /dev/mx1
```

But if I run this command from cli it works fine. I believe because of the asynchronous nature of systemd services /dev/mx1 is not ready when udisk2 is trying to mount usb hdd.

1. What rule should I write instead?
2. Is there any good guide on Internet how to write custom automounting rules especially for ntfs file systems?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error with `udisksctl mount -b /foo/bar`. Probably the special rule is triggerd too early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the reason why *udev* and *udisks2* didn't work together. But I found a solution for my problem [here](http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/12758). Below is a simple example how to implement automount of a ntfs usb hdd. First is a script *mount.sh* to mount a drive

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /media/usbhdd
mount -t ntfs-3g -o locale=en_IE.UTF-8,fmask=0113,dmask=0002,uid=storage-user,gid=storage-group /dev/mx1 /media/usbhdd
```

Then we create a systemd unit in */etc/systemd/system/mount-hdd.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=mount usb hdd
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/scripts/storage/mount.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And finally udev rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", SYMLINK+="mx%n"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="sd*1", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start mount-hdd"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial_number>", RUN+="/bin/umount /media/usbhdd", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/usbhdd"
```